# Keycloak, not returning access token if update password action selected

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am calling `/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token` to get access token by sending below content in body,
`grant_type=password&client_id=example-docker-jaxrs-app&username=user&password=password&client_secret=1d27aedd-11c2-4ed2-97d5-c586e1f9b3cd`

but when I put update password as required action to user from keycloak admin console getting following error when try to get token by above mentioned api,

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Account is not fully set up"
}
```

one more thing, What is difference in 2 setting, Temporary password and Update password Required action ?

[image: Temporary flag here in users credential tab]

[image: Update password as required action in user details tab]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you mark the password as temporary a user action to `update password` is marked as required.

And until the password has been updated/set by the user i.e. this action has been completed, you won't be able to get an access token using this user since the account is not "fully setup" and is in a kind of intermediate state where an action is required to complete the setup.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  then how can somebody validate username/password first time. I do not want to user keycloak screen I have our own login page, and we are using /token api for validateing username/password.

Comment: You can avoid marking the password as temporary. No required action will be added to the user profile and the credentials can be used to get a token

Comment: @ShaileshNarkhede have you found any solution ? if yes, would you mind to share it with us))? thanks in advance

Comment: as said in above comment, do not mar password as temporary, then updateAction will not get added and access token is returned.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update the password then update it and do not mark it temporary, If you mark temporary then after that just remove the update password from Required Actions box.

Comment: thank you your solution fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but the solution for me was not in the answers yet. I'm on Keycloak version 24.0.1.

I had to go to the realm's authentication (left menu) >> required actions (tab) >> turn off the enabled required actions. And then after that I got the access_token and no more  complaints about "Account is not fully set up".

Comment: I also had the "same problem" in this version, and did this (more precisely the Verify Profile option) and it fixes it

Answer (score 1):

in my case my user has **Required user actions ->verify email**
After remove **verify email** access token generated successfully
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ldap user federation, I review some tables of SSO and delete the data from user_required_action and clear user cache, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

rest your password  and then click on the cross symbol (x) present in the ----Required Users Action in the update Password and then save the user details it will work

Answer (score 0):

For me, first name and last name were missing.

To find it, I impersonated the user from the admin dashboard. It essentially asked me to complete the name/last name fields and I found the issue.